# Average Time between Two Date Fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a MySQL database that tracks call center phone contacts.  Phone agents put in call information with an Access application, and I'm generating a report based off that information, either in Access or Excel VBA.

Each contact is saved in a contact table, with information about the contact, and 'ContactDateTimeInitiate' and 'ContactDateTimeComplete' date fields.  There are fields in the record for the type of call, and I need to pull information based on quite a few different views.  For instance, for a single category, for a department, for the month, for the day, etc.

My question is, how do I generate an average of (contactdatetimecomplete-contactdatetimeinitiate)?  I accomplished it using some inefficient loops using multiple recordsets, but I'm sure there is an easier way to do this.

This is returning a number in the hundreds- it should be close to 5 or 10 minutes:

rst.Open "Select avg(timediff(contactdatetimecomplete,contactdatetimeinitiate)) as expr1 from contacts", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

I'm connecting to the DB just fine, the issue is in the SQL Syntax.  I haven't been able to find anything else out there. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
                          contactdatetimeinitiate, 
                          contactdatetimecomplete)
           ) AS average
```

This should give you the average contact duration in seconds.

If you're really worrying about fractional-second time intervals, you could try using `MICROSECOND` in place of `SECOND`.  In this case you'll need

```
     SELECT AVG( 0.000001 * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, 
                              contactdatetimeinitiate, 
                              contactdatetimecomplete)
               ) AS average
```

This answer is valid for MySQL.

Comment: I haven't used these functions in MySQL before, but did a quick lookup. It appears that his mistake was using TIMEDIFF (which returns a time) and TIMESTAMPDIFF (which returns an integer). +1

Comment: Perfect, fixed instantly.  Thank you both!  Timestampdiff returns the value in seconds, and I'm using DateAdd("s", rst.Fields("expr1"), testDate) to generate the formatted date.  Thanks sincerely.